# Borewell circuit box button coming out

Tags: circuit-breaker, well-pump

When i turn on my borewell, after some minutes it stop pulling water and there is a button on circuit board which come out. When i press it in and restart the borewell it just start working and after some time same happen.

What is the purpose of this button and why it come out?

[image]

## This is the button

[image]

## Internal circuit

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That button is a circuit breaker, which is protecting your wiring from overload.

The fact that it pops out means that your pump is drawing too much current for some reason. It's time to pull it up and check it out. There's either some corrosion or something is blocking the impeller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using 3 Core 40/76 wire on submersible domestic  borewell. Where should i actually look?

Comment: @YOU should check the physical pump, make sure there is nothing clogging it up or something. Aside from that, an electrician or pump repair person would need to check.

Answer (score 0):

It is a thermal fuse which switches off if the circuit uses too much current. If it comes out regularly that means something is wrong/broken and the equipment should be inspected by a qualified electrical engineer.

Answer (score 0):

The breaker is rated for 6A and current should be measured to verify  that the breaker is performing or the motor is overloaded.

I would have expected the Chinese OEM to circle the appropriate options on the label but I see that was not done.

Motors can draw up to 3x to 5x rated current on starting and if this persists long than the thermal breaker’s time to heat up, it trips.  Measure the current and determine what maintenance is needed or if the workload has changed making the choices undersized.  E.g. is silt filter clogged?